# python - load .json into dictionary fails

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary

I am trying to load everything from a .json file to a dictionary in python.

Can anyone explain to me why the below doesn't work?

```
my_dict = {}

def change_dict(str_file_path, dict_param):
  with open(str_file_path) as opened_file:
    dict_param = json.load(opened_file)
  opened_file.close

change_dict(my_file_path, my_dict)
```

The path I use for the file is correct, and the above works when instead of using a dictionary parameter I use my_dict directly (but this is not what I want to do).

I have been using Pycharm and the visual aid "shows" me that it treats the dictionary parameter as something that isn't getting used later on which also doesn't make any sense.

[image: pycharm]

Printing my_dict shows {} . I guess if I tried to return the dictionary parameter as a value to my global dictionary it would work (but for now I don't want to do that) but I want to know why the above won't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just a side note. `opened_file.close` is not needed since you're using `with open`

Comment: What do you want to do? Read a json file into a dict? If that is it - see my answer.

Comment: This line `dict_param = json.load(opened_file)` only rebinds the name `dict_param` to a new dictionary within the scope of the `change_dict()` func. You need to return the new dict and assign to `my_dict` in global space to change it.

Comment: @SuperShoot, so in `change_dict(my_file_path, my_dict)`, `my_dict` won't actually "replace" the parameter? I didn't know that. I thought it would act like a variable. But then again if I do `dict_param["apple"] = "banana"` it would work when I call `change_dict(my_file_path, my_dict)` and print it. Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your code:

```
my_dict = {}

def change_dict(str_file_path, dict_param):
  with open(str_file_path) as opened_file:
    dict_param = json.load(opened_file)  # **
  opened_file.close()

change_dict(my_file_path, my_dict)  # *
```

At (*), you are passing in a reference to `my_dict`. This "reference" is just a variable storing the address of `my_dict` (if you know C/C++, this is like a pointer). Let's call this "address variable" A. Note that A points to a block of memory that is `my_dict` and not the object itself. Now, at (**), you assign this "address variable"/pointer to another block of memory returned by `json.load(...)`. All it does is to write another address into this "address variable"/pointer, leaving the original block of memory (`my_dict`) unmodified.

However, if you don't change the value of the pointer, but rather, invoke a function to modify `my_dict` such as [`update()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp) then you can modify `my_dict` inside the function. E.g.:

```
import json

my_dict = {}


def change_dict(str_file_path, dict_param):
    with open(str_file_path) as opened_file:
        tmp = json.load(opened_file)
        dict_param.update(tmp)

change_dict('test.json', my_dict)
print(my_dict)
```

where my `test.json` file is:

```
{
  "apple": "banana",
  "pineapple": "papaya"
}
```

Comment: That's it! I am gonna have to dive more into the details, but this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are returning nothing.

Try:

```
def change_dict(str_file_path):
  with open(str_file_path) as opened_file:
    dict_param = json.load(opened_file)
  return dict_param

my_dict = change_dict(my_file_path)
```

If you insist on using globals (bad practice in this case) you can try:

```
dict_param = {}
def change_dict(str_file_path):
  global dict_param
  with open(str_file_path) as opened_file:
    dict_param = json.load(opened_file)

change_dict(my_file_path)
```

Note that your function automatically returns `None` if you do not return a value.

Here is a simple example using globals in general:

```
my_dict = {}

def something(key, value):
    global my_dict
    my_dict[key] = value

def something_else():
    global my_dict
    my_dict = {'c': 'd'}

def non_global():
    my_dict = {'e': 'f'}

something('a', 'b')
print(my_dict)  ## outputs: {'a': 'b'}
something_else()
print(my_dict)  ## outputs: {'c': 'd'}
non_global()
print(my_dict)  ## outputs: {'c': 'd'}
```

It is generally better practice for the function to return the answer than to store it in a global variable somewhere out of scope.

Comment: Hey, I was trying to populate some global dictionaries from a function that would have a dictionary parameter so I can "send" the dictionaries to that function as input. I think what you did above with the global is not the same since you are skipping the parameter and just populate it directly. The return-way, that you mentioned first works, but there is a case that the dictionary would be huge and I found out returning was slower than just "editing". But based on the answers I think I will have to go back to return.

Comment: Ok, remember to like and accept the answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

def load_data(path):
   with open(path,'r') as f:
      return json.load(f)
```